# Average counts in a column with condition of another column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loHJY.png)

**I need to find out the average close days of request Recycling**

Please help me.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: In particular, off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by request and get the average.This will give average for each group

```
df.groupby("request")["Days to Close"].mean()
```